# Angular.JS data binding

Tags: angularjs

I have started learning angular.js but I am kind of having trouble understanding the data binding and scopes.

Here is my Html file :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"    />
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">   </script>
    <title>Egghead</title>
    </head>
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
1. <div>
    NAME : <input type = "text" name = "name" data-ng-model="data.name"/> 
    Typed Name : <b>{{data.name}}</b>
    <br><br>
    EMAIL: <input type = "email" name = "email" data-ng-model="data.email"/>
    Typed Email : <b>{{data.email}}</b>
</div>

2. <div data-ng-controller="firstController">
    NAME : <input type = "text" name = "name" data-ng-model="data.name"/> 
    Typed Name : <b>{{data.name}}</b>
    <br><br>
    EMAIL: <input type = "email" name = "email" data-ng-model="data.email"/>
    Typed Email : <b>{{data.email}}</b>
</div>

3. <div data-ng-controller="secondController">
    NAME : <input type = "text" name = "name" data-ng-model="data.name"/> 
    Typed Name : <b>{{data.name}}</b>
    <br><br>
    EMAIL: <input type = "email" name = "email" data-ng-model="data.email"/>
    Typed Email : <b>{{data.email}}</b>
</div>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I have this module for my current html :

```
(function(){
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('firstController', function($scope, $rootScope) {

        /*$rootScope.data = {name : "root", email : "root@gmail.com"};
        $scope.data = {name : "Ishan", email : "soni.ishan.nitj@gmail.com"};*/
    });


    myApp.controller('secondController', function($scope) {
        /*$scope.data = {name : "Divyan", email : "soni.divyan@gmail.com"};*/
    });

})();
```

any changes that I make in any of the textbox for say the "name" input reflects and is bound everywhere. Example I make a change in the input text with name = "name" inside the second controller, the value in the text box for first also changes, but when I remove the comments from my javascript file, any change I make in the second controller's input box are not reflected in the first's input box. Why?

Comment: If you mean they are not reflected in the first as in firstController, is because the $scope is different. firstController has his own scope and secondController has his. If you want to tie them together from worst option to best option you can use $rootScope, nest controllers and call parent or just use a service

Answer (score 1):

`$rootScope` is parent of all scopes, so if you assign property to it, it will be available everywhere in views. Every controller has `$scope`, you have two sibling controllers, so they have different scopes, if you want to share data between controllers, you shall use service. Like this:

```
myApp.factory('dataSrvc', function () {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return {
                name : "Divyan",
                email : "soni.divyan@gmail.com"
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Then inject it into controllers:

```
myApp.controller('firstController', function($scope, dataSrvc) {
    scope.data = dataSrvc.getData();
});


myApp.controller('secondController', function($scope, dataSrvc) {
    scope.data = dataSrvc.getData();
});
```

In this case changes in first controller will not reflect on second and vice versa, because `getData` returns new instance of object every time (with same data).

Comment: So when I have nothing commented in my js file, I have 3 data objects. 1 at the root scope and two at the scope of the respective controllers. Updating any one of them just updates the respective data object. But when I have commented the code there is a single data object that is at the root scope that is being updated by everyone?

Comment: @IshanSoni yes, if you only have data in rootScope, both controller's views will use same data object so it will change everywhere.